# Problems setting two local nodes on the same computer

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, nodes

i'm setting two local nodes on the same computer as different users (two different sessions). The problem is that i can't make them be peers.

Command to wake main node:

```
geth    --identity "MainNode" \
        --rpc \
        --rpcport 8000 \
        --rpccorsdomain "*" \
        --datadir "/home/ubuntu/ethereum" \
        --port "30303" \
        --nodiscover \
        --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" \
        --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" \
        --autodag \
        --networkid 10165211 \
        --nat "any" console init /home/ubuntu/ethereum/CustomGenesis.json
```

Command to wake second node:

```
geth    --identity "My Node" \
        --rpc \
        --rpcport 8001 \
        --rpccorsdomain "*" \
        --datadir "/home/xxxx/ethereum" \
        --port "30304" \
        --nodiscover \
        --ipcdisable \
        --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" \
        --autodag \
        --networkid 10165211 \
        --nat "any" console init /home/xxxx/ethereum/CustomGenesis.json
```

But when i start the nodes, and i use the command admin.nodeInfo i find this in the first node:

```
admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://34f8ec977f25f4a85d4d7debac748fd82851b75ca670b2ece234c9a26a493fb995fca0021b9eee6cb2ccfa98a934cdb4a8590e4a4140a1077575f94a82468129@[::]:30303?discport=0",
  id: "34f8ec977f25f4a85d4d7debac748fd82851b75ca670b2ece234c9a26a493fb995fca0021b9eee6cb2ccfa98a934cdb4a8590e4a4140a1077575f94a82468129",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30303",
  name: "Geth/v1.4.12-stable/linux/go1.5.1/MainNode",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30303
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 17179869184,
      genesis: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      network: 10165211
    }
  }
}
```

And THIS, on the second one:

```
 admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://34f8ec977f25f4a85d4d7debac748fd82851b75ca670b2ece234c9a26a493fb995fca0021b9eee6cb2ccfa98a934cdb4a8590e4a4140a1077575f94a82468129@[::]:30304?discport=0",
  id: "34f8ec977f25f4a85d4d7debac748fd82851b75ca670b2ece234c9a26a493fb995fca0021b9eee6cb2ccfa98a934cdb4a8590e4a4140a1077575f94a82468129",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30304",
  name: "Geth/v1.4.12-stable/linux/go1.5.1/My Node",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30304
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 1024,
      genesis: "0x1a8c903ab9d8b7bec7ba8b15dab33a3418c90dbf8f73ec3086d34b4e17e017e6",
      head: "0x1a8c903ab9d8b7bec7ba8b15dab33a3418c90dbf8f73ec3086d34b4e17e017e6",
      network: 10165211
    }
  }
}
```

Even when the CustomGenesis.json file is a pure copy of each other (completely) we can see some strange things:

- the enode ID is the same in both cases. It should not be.
- The port changes (obviously it must be done that way). It's OK.
- The difficulty is not the same, it should be.
- The genesis hash and the head are not the same. I guess they should be.

I'm sure is not a Genesis.json file problem, as i've even tried to use the same file for both nodes but the same i'm explaining here happenned to me.

Any idea on where's the error/mistake/bug?

THANK YOU.

Comment: The difficulty is not the same,node 2 not sync with the whole blockchain.

Comment: Are you using different datadirs? Also, what do you mean by two sessions? I think you're accessing the same datadir from both the sessions.

Comment: I am not, i got different datadirs as you can see in the code.
Two sessions: two different user-sessions (xxxx and ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me:

When this happens, it may seem to be a corruption of some data.
The solution is as easy as deleting every datadir and subfolders. This will mean you to start from zero (or saving some data, as accounts if you backup them before) but it worked.

In my case:

```
sudo rm -r /home/ubuntu/ethereum/
sudo rm -r /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/
sudo rm -r /home/xxxx/ethereum
```